# conditional xpath statement

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

This is a piece of HTML from which I'd like to extract information from:

```
  <li>
    <p><strong class="more-details-section-header">Provenance</strong></p>
    <p>Galerie Max Hetzler, Berlin<br>Acquired from the above by the present owner</p>
  </li>
```

I'd like to have an xpath expression which extracts the content of the 2nd `<p> ... </p>` depending if there's a sibling before with `<p> ... Provenance ... </p>`

This is to where I got so far:

```
if "Provenance" in response.xpath('//strong[@class="more-details-section-header"]/text()').extract():
            print("provenance = yes")
```

But how do I get to `Galerie Max Hetzler, Berlin<br>Acquired from the above by the present owner` ?

I tried

```
if "Provenance" in response.xpath('//strong[@class="more-details-section-header"]/text()').extract():
            print("provenance = yes ", response.xpath('//strong[@class="more-details-section-header"]/following-sibling::p').extract())
```

But am getting `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
//p[preceding-sibling::p[1]/strong='Provenance']/text()
```

Comment: Or to be more precise "//p[preceding-sibling::p[1]='Provenance']/text()"